# Should I encapsulate the update method inside of object or have method which accepts an object to update?

Tags: c#, inheritance, static, singleton, encapsulation

I actually have 2 questions related to each other:

1. I have an object (class) called, say MyClass which holds data from my database. Currently I have a list of these objects ( List < MyClass > ) that resides in a singleton in a "communal area". I feel it's easier to manage the data this way and I fail to see how passing a class around from object to object is beneficial over a singleton (I would be happy if someone can tell me why). Anyway, the data may change in the database from outside my program and so I have to update the data every so often. To update the list of the MyClass I have a method called say, Update, written in another class which accepts a list of MyClass. This updates all the instances of MyClass in the list.

   However would it be better instead to encapulate the Update() method inside the MyClass object, so instead I would say:

   ```
   foreach(MyClass obj in MyClassList) {
       obj.update();
   }
   ```

   What is a better implementation and why?
2. The update method requires a XML reader. I have written an XML reader class which is basically a wrapper over the standard XML reader the language natively provides which provides application specific data collection. Should the XML reader class be in anyway in the "inheritance path" of the MyClass object - the MyClass objects inherits from the XML reader because it uses a few methods. I can't see why it should. I don't like the idea of declaring an instance of the XML Reader class inside of MyClass and an MyClass object is meant to be a simple "record" from the database and I feel giving it loads of methods, other object instances is a bit messy. Perhaps my XML reader class should be static but C#'s native XMLReader isn't static?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I would suggest putting an update method in MyClass.  It sounds like you may be instantiating multiple copies of the same object, and perhaps a better solution would be to update the original MyClass objects directly through their update methods.

This would also give you the added advantage of being able to update individual objects in the future and should be more maintainable.

For your second question, it sounds like MyClass contains data from a database, making it an entity object.  Entity objects shouldn't contain business logic, so I think you'd be okay having a Service class use the XMLReader to perform operations on the data and then use the getters/setters to manipulate the data in the object.  Same as before, this has the advantage of keeping your code loosely coupled and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not include Update() within the class.  I know it seems tempting because it the update call "easier" but what that would be creating dependencies.  (Presumably) MyClass contains db data because it is a domain object which is represents the state of some real world "unit" (tangible, conceptual, or otherwise). If you include an update() method; now you're domain object is not only responsible for representing the state of some logical "thing", but it is also responsible for persistence logic (save, load, new, delete).  You'd be better off creating a service which handles those responsibilities.  This relates to the design principle of  high cohesion, ie. each class has only 1 responsibility (or type of responsibility at least). eg....   persistenceService.saveUser(myUser);
2. This is basically the same question, except now you are talking about making your class directly dependant (as a descendant in this case) of a specific type of persistence (writing to xml file) which is even worse than having your class be dependent on persistence in a more generalized way.

Think about it like this when trying to make design decisions... plan on change (instability, chaos, or whatever you would like to call it).  What if a month from now you need to switch out the XML persistance for a database?  Or what if you all of a sudden have to deal with MyClassVariantA, MyClassVariantB, MyClassVariantC?  By minimizing dependencies, when you do have to change something it won't necessitate a cascade of changes throughout every other part of your application.